# How to check column exist or not before select that column from table

Tags: mysql, if-statement, select

Below is the query I used to select multiple columns from one of my tables.
I get the column names from user to select from the table.
If the user gives a wrong column name it shows Unknown column error. How can I check if that column exists in the table before going to select?

```
SELECT `address_id`,`address_firstname`,` afserfw` 
FROM `patsm_addresstable` 
WHERE `address_id`='28'
LIMIT 0, 25
```

This would give the following error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column ' afserfw' in 'field list'
```

Comment: Why is a user defining what columns to select? What is the purpose of this query? Alternatively give the user a select drop down of columns that exist

Comment: `show columns from tablename;` will give you a list of columns. You have to check before you send the query (or just execute the query and return this error, it might have the same effect as checking the fieldlist first and then return a manual error like `Unknown column ' afserfw'` yourself.) You cannot check inside a query if a column the query wants to use exists (e.g. you cannot use `if exists column afserfw then afserfw else null`)

Comment: Hi matt, It should be user defined because the user can create custom fields. for my requirement i want users mobile number to send some notification message. No need to show all the fields in drop down and mobile fields doesn't have any particular identification to get them alone. Thankyou

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments Solaflare.

Answer (score 1):

This query will give you a list of columns in a particular table with their datatypes.

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
   AND TABLE_NAME = 'tablename'
```

You can, when constructing a query against any table, use this resultset to determine whether a given column exists.

But be careful: a web application allowing end-users to give you column names is hard to make secure against intrusion by cybercrooks.